# Jquery — Set child to fill remaining width of parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building a responsive layout. I would like to know if anyone knows a way through JS/jQuery which I can set children to fill the remaining space of a parent only if there is space to fill (to the right).

### **Layout when above 900px**

[image: above 900px]

### **Layout when below 900px**

[image]

### **HTML for reference**

```css
.row {
  width: 100%;
}

.colm-span-2 {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 15px auto;
  padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  background-clip: content-box;
}

.colm-span-2 {
  width: 33.3333333333%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .colm-span-2 {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="colm-span-2">
    <div class="bg-white">
      <div class="cont-span-1">
        <h2>Test</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="colm-span-2">
    <div class="bg-cta-green">
      <div class="cont-span-1">
        <h2>Test</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="colm-span-2">
    <div class="bg-dark-purple">
      <div class="cont-span-1">
        <h2>Test</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey. I've added the CSS

Comment: Click the "edit snippet" link while [edit]ing your question. Click the Run button. Notice how that is different from your screenshot? Add CSS until it's like your screenshot. This will get you the best answers for your issue.

Comment: Just add an extra class to the last item and override the width in your media query

Comment: Certainly not possible with CSS as it cannot detect the last item in a "row".

Comment: @Paulie_D  `:last-child` selector can do this. [https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding:

```
.colm-span-2:last-child {
    width: 100%;
}
```

to your media query. This will change the final `.colm-span-2` to have a 100% width.

Comment: I should have mentioned that this is to be used as a template. The last child will not always be left alone.

Comment: @NeilMorgan Edit your question with the exact conditions and create a [mcve] then.  There's nothing worse than a question that keeps changing as the answers come in

Answer (score 1):

With flexbox and `:last-child` (assuming you have rows) this is possible

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.bg-white {
  background: whitesmoke;
}

.bg-cta-green {
  background: green;
}

.bg-dark-purple {
  background: rebeccapurple;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.colm-span-2 {
  flex: 0 0 33%;
  margin: .25em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.colm-span-2:last-child {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="colm-span-2">
    <div class="bg-white">
      <div class="cont-span-1">
        <h2>Test</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="row">
  <div class="colm-span-2">
    <div class="bg-white">
      <div class="cont-span-1">
        <h2>Test</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="colm-span-2">
    <div class="bg-cta-green">
      <div class="cont-span-1">
        <h2>Test</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="colm-span-2">
    <div class="bg-dark-purple">
      <div class="cont-span-1">
        <h2>Test</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="colm-span-2">
    <div class="bg-white">
      <div class="cont-span-1">
        <h2>Test</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="colm-span-2">
    <div class="bg-cta-green">
      <div class="cont-span-1">
        <h2>Test</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```